# Проблема с созданием экземпляра объекта

Tags: c++, mfc

Есть такой кусок кода:

```
class CAnimation
{
public:
    CAnimation()
    {
       m_iCurrentFrame = 1;
       m_iTotalFrames = 30;
       for (int i = 0; i < m_iTotalFrames; i++)
       {
          Frame f;
          float flFrac = 1.0 / (float)FrameS_NUM;
          f.m_flTime = i * flFrac;
          for (int j = 0; j < g_pDoc->m_pCurState->m_oaBones.GetCount(); j++)
          {
             Frame::Key fk;
             fk.m_pBone = (CBone*)g_pDoc->m_pCurState->m_oaBones.GetAt(j);
             f.m_aKeys.add(fk);
          }
          m_aFrames.add(f);
       }
    }
    class Frame : public CObject
    {
    public:
        Frame() {};
        class Key : public CObject
        {
        public:
            Key(){};
            matrix m_matrix;
            quat m_quat;
            CBone* m_pBone;
        };
        array<Key> m_aKeys;
        float m_flTime;
        vec3 _vRootOffset;
    };
   CString      m_strName;
   int m_iCurrentFrame;
   int m_iFramesCount;
   array<Frame> m_aFrames;
   array<matrix> m_aCurrentState;
};
```

Создаю объект

```
CAnimation* pNewAnmation = new CAnimation;
```

Во время инициализации все заполняется, и все гуд. Но сразу же после этого во фреймах отсутствуют ключи (пусто). В анимации есть все фреймы.
С чем это может быть связано?

UPD.
Frame Copy

```
    Frame& operator=(const Frame& other)
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < m_aKeys.getCount(); i++)
        {
            m_aKeys[i] = other.m_aKeys[i];
        }
        m_flTime = other.m_flTime;
        _vRootOffset = other._vRootOffset;
        return *this; 
    }
```

Key Copy

```
Key& operator=(const Key& other)
{ 
    m_matrix = other.m_matrix; 
    m_quat = other.m_quat; 
    m_pBone = other.m_pBone; 
    return *this; 
}
```

Comment: Конструктор в закрытой части: забыли сделать доступным

Comment: Вероятно из-за отсутствия конструкторов копирования у классов Frame и Key

Comment: на самом деле в открытой, тут забыл написать, исправил

Comment: @AlexeyNikolaev смотрите UPD, они есть, но все равно та же проблема

Comment: Это операторы присваивания, а нужны конструкторы копирования. Frame(const Frame&); и Key(const Key&);

Comment: нашел проблему, спасибо. При копировании запрашивал число ключей еще не созданного фрейма( то есть их 0 )

Comment: @MaxSkyline, опубликуйте решение проблемы в ответе